# Deploying an Web API2.0 with angular application on azure

Tags: c#, angularjs, azure, asp.net-web-api

We've create the Project Using Web API 2.0 and Angular 9 as front end.

Now we want to deploy this application on azure VM using iis service on Which we dnt have much experience.

Any help can be appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps to publish your Web API and UI to Azure:

1. Create an Azure account Step
2. You should have a subscription to your Azure account
3. Add app service to be deployed to your API
4. Create a web app for your UI to be published
5. If you have DB connectivity in your API you need to add Azure SQL DB
6. In Step 3 and Step 4 you will get the Separate Publish URL

**Deploying asp.net web application from visual studio to Azure**

In the solution explorer, right-click on the web application project and click Publish

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Select Azure and click Next

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Select Azure App Service and click Next

[image: Screenshot for reference]

Click on the + sign

[image: Screenshot for reference]

- Provide a Name for the App Service. This is the name that will be used to access the web application
- Select your Subscription and Resource Group
- Finally select your hosting plan. If you wish to use a free hosting plan. Click on
  the New link
- Provide a name, location and the size for the Hosting Plan. It is the size that determines what you pay and what features you get. I have selected the Free pricing tier for illustration
- Remember, to host a web application in Azure we need App Service and an App Service Plan
- Now we are creating them (App Service and App Service Plan) from within visual studio instead of going through the azure portal.
- Click OK and the finish.

[image: Screenshot for reference]

In a few minutes your app will be deployed to Azure and you can access it using the URL

Comment: Thank you this helps but how  can I publish the angular code to with WEb APi